# How to tell autoconf to run specific commands in with 'make install'

Tags: cmake, autoconf

I am on OSX 12.6.8, and I succesfully generated a makefile by using autoconf by creating configure.ac and makefile.am as indicated in this [tutorial](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2016/03/10/autoconf-tutorial-1/)

By running `autoconf`, then `./configure` and `make`, my program is succesfully compiled. I would like to tell autoconf to run a specific command , e.g. '`echo good morning`' when running `make install`.

How should I modify configure.ac and makefile.am to do this ?

Thanks !